# working with Node js Await/Async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

This is  my axios Request to call the API.

```
export function axiosGet (url) {
      return opsutils.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return 'An error occured..' + error;
        })
    }
```

From here i'm calling it asynchrously

```
async getDirList(data){
      this.domainDir=data.domain_name
      var apiurl="some URL"
      var stat = await axiosGet(apiurl)
      if (status){
        this.domainlog= stat
    }
```

From here i'm calling the async func defined above

```
Notify(data){
    var filelist = this.getDirList(data)
    if(filelist){
           var status =  createNotification(data.domain_name,message_stripped,'Degrading web server performance')
}
```

The ideal should be like this that it should go forward only after the promise is resolved ,right now the var filelist got empty.
How do i get to solve this problem ?Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't `return` a plain string in case of an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `this.getDirList(data)` is not being accessed asynchronously as well. Remember, because that is async now, it's returning a promise, so you either need to chain it with `.then()`:

```
Notify(data){
    var filelist = this.getDirList(data)
        .then(data => {
            var status = createNotification(data.domain_name,message_stripped,'Degrading web server performance')
        });

}
```

Or turn `Notify()` into an async function as well:

```
async Notify(data){
    var filelist = await this.getDirList(data);
    if(filelist){
           var status =  createNotification(data.domain_name,message_stripped,'Degrading web server performance')
}
```

Additionally, **make sure you're actually returning data from `getDirList`** so you can utilize the return value when you await it.

Comment: @Rohit: There's a good tutorial [here](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9) that I recommend checking out, if you're new to promises/tasks.